# Unable to pass small image to modal popup and display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am creating image elements of load of a page and written the code in AJAX POST jquery method for it. So small icons of image are coming on page. When I click on the image on document.ready(onclick) it must open big in modal pop up but it is not opening.However blank pop up is opening.

**loadup.js code**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/loadimages_f.php",
     dataType : 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        //alert(result);
         if(result==0){
       $("#friends_list_insert").after(" No Friends Yet...");
   }
    else{   
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        {
             var PP_PATH;
            PP_PATH="php/"+result[i].Photo_URL;
          var li_post="<li class='imggalli' style='list-style:none;'><a 
    href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal2' class='thumbnailimg' title='Image"+i+"'><img src='"+PP_PATH+"' style='margin:2px;width:65px;height:65px;' class='img-responsive' id='img"+i+"'></a></li>";

          $("#img_gallery_append").append(li_post);
    }
   }
 }
});
```

**now on page code**

```
   // Function for image pop up
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('img').on('click', function() {
         $("#showImg").empty();
          // alert(this.id);
         var image = $(this).attr("src");
         $("#showImg").append("<img class='img-responsive' src='" + image + "' />")
     })
  });
```

What is the problem ? Could anyone help please ? ( Objective is opening the small image on the modal pop up..)

Answer (score 0):

try to correct this

```
PP_PATH="php/"+result[i].Photo_URL;
```

with

```
PP_PATH="php/"+result.d[i].Photo_URL;
```

because `result` is object, and you need to catch the data with `d`

Comment: At this point I am appending the i'th position value to the src for images and it is populating all images correctly. But problem is after the populate. It is clickable but on modal pop up blank is coming.However,I tried ur suggestion but it doesn't effect